# Working with HTTPS, non-secure services and ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-service, security

**Situation:**
I am currently working with an app that is required to be delivered over HTTPS because of an organizational security requirement.  I currently do not have access to this servers administration, just the application code itself.

**Problem:**
The application relies on services from ArcGIS server (I have access to these servers).  These services are only delivered via HTTP since we do not have the server configured for HTTPS.  This causes issues with the app, since it is secure and requesting non-secure services.

**Question**
How do I get around this?  I am guessing the best way would be to enable HTTPS on our ArcGIS Service server, but I would like to avoid doing that if at all possible.  Can I use ESRI's JavaScript API Proxy rules to solve this (this would be optimal)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own ArcGis servers you can [enable SSL](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Enabling_SSL_on_ArcGIS_Server/0154000005q0000000/) on the servers for communication.

An important thing to note is that once you have SSL enabled and running over https, you then need to go and manually [disable HTTP communication](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Disabling_HTTP_access_to_ArcGIS_Server/0154000005v4000000/) as the server will try and run both if you let it.